# Maximum weighted matching for directed (non-bipartite) graphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs, matching

This post concerns mainly non-bipartite graphs.

Edmonds (1961) have proposed the [Blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) to solve the maximum matching problem for undirected graphs. The best implementation of it is due to [Micali and Vazirani (1980)](https://doi.org/10.1109/SFCS.1980.12): $\mathcal O(|E|\sqrt{|V|})$ time. There is a version of the Blossom algorithm for weighted graphs ([Kolmogorov, 2009](http://doi.org/10.1007/s12532-009-0002-8)), but still it concerns only undirected graphs.

Are you aware of any implementation of the Blossom algorithm for weighted directed graphs? I could not find one.

Comment: As far as I know, the notion of matching is independent of the orientation of the edges. What is the difference for you between a matching in a directed graph and the same set of edges in an undirected graph where the weight of an edge is defined as the maximum weight of both orientation ?

Comment: Let's say for example, I start from my directed (weighted) graph G(V,E) and create a bipartite (weighted) graph G1(X,Y,E1) (that is obviously nondirected) in such a way that V=X=Y and E1 captures the orientation of E (by only accounting for edges e=(x,y) where x (resp. y) is a source (resp. end) node of the corresponding edge in G). Bipartite graphs matching is not related to edges' orientation, as you rightly say, but still I could capture the orientation of my graph G in the maximum matching of G1. Solving Hungarian takes O(n^3).

Comment: It could be nice if there is a direct implementation of Edmonds algorithms that takes into account the orientation of edges, and could be probably more efficient than O(n^3).